# Can't connect to Ethernet port on RPI

Tags: raspbian, networking, boot, ethernet, setup

I have an Rasberry Pi B. I have copied Raspbian to SD card. I plugged RPI into TV and set it up. I enabled SSH at boot.

I rebooted, and took it to my laptop. I connected the laptop and Pi via Ethernet. I am using Ubuntu on laptop. I connect it, and I get a little spinning orb in the top right corner showing that it's connecting.

It never connects though. I always get a Disconnected popup telling me that it failed to connect via wire.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Pi, by default, will be expecting to be given an IP address.  Are you running a DHCP server on your laptop?

Comment: if you can see the output on the Pi run "ifconfig -a" then run the same on the laptop (Mac/Linux) or "ipconfig /all" (Windows) and make sure the ip address are in the same range, added them to your question if you are unsure.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. The pi is looking for a DHCP server, but when you plug it straight into your laptop it won't be able to find one by default. What I did is (on Windows only) I went to network settings > change adapter settings > my *WIFI* adapter > properties > sharing and check the box marked "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connect" and finally select your *ETHERNET* adapter from the drop down. Then reboot the pi or reconnect it and if all goes well it should connect. Then you can use ifconfig (on the pi) or a tool like nmap (on your laptop) to find it's address and SSH into it.

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry pi and your laptop need to be on the same subnet. Therefore go to your internet settings on your mac and set a DHCP with manual address, e.g. 192.168.1.10. Then on your RPi, connect it to a screen and keyboard and give it a manual address such as 192.168.1.20. When the RPi has booted, type in

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Now look for the eth0 line which corresponds to the Raspberry pi ethernet port and edit the file to look similar to this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Once the file has been updated, use ctrl x to save and exit. Now reboot the pi and test if the connection works by pinging the laptop: `ping 192.168.10`.

Hope this helps!